Yarn resolution for loader-utils not processing
I have a react project with a dependency on react-scripts@5.0.1. Snyk flags a transitive vulnerability issue with loader-utils@2.0.2 so I've added a yarn resolution to get the correct version. However, it seems to be getting ignored. How can I force yarn to load the 2.0.4 version of loader-utils?
I've tried this resolution format:
"resolutions": {
        "**/browserify-sign": "4.2.3",
        "**/@babel/traverse":"7.25.3",
        "**/decode-uri-component":"0.2.2",
        "**/nth-check":"2.0.1",
        "**/semver":"7.5.2",
        "**/ws":"7.5.10",
        "**/follow-redirects":"1.15.6",
        "**/elliptic": "6.5.7",
        "**/loader-utils":"2.0.4",
        "**/minimist":"1.2.6"
      }

And this resolution format:
"resolutions": {
        "**/browserify-sign": "4.2.3",
        "**/@babel/traverse":"7.25.3",
        "**/decode-uri-component":"0.2.2",
        "**/nth-check":"2.0.1",
        "**/semver":"7.5.2",
        "**/ws":"7.5.10",
        "**/follow-redirects":"1.15.6",
        "**/elliptic": "6.5.7",
        "**/loader-utils@2.0.0":"2.0.4",
        "**/minimist":"1.2.6",
        "**/loader-utils@1.0.0": "1.4.1"
      }

npm ls loader-utils provides this:

└─┬ my-app@1.0.0 -> .\applications\my-app
  ├─┬ babel-loader@8.3.0
  │ └── loader-utils@2.0.2
  ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@6.4.1
  │ └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ file-loader@6.2.0
  │ └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@4.5.2
  │ └── loader-utils@1.4.0
  ├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  │ ├─┬ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.15
  │ │ └── loader-utils@2.0.4
  │ ├─┬ @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
  │ │ └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped
  │ ├─┬ react-dev-utils@12.0.1
  │ │ └── loader-utils@3.3.1
  │ └─┬ resolve-url-loader@4.0.0
  │   ├─┬ adjust-sourcemap-loader@4.0.0
  │   │ └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped
  │   └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped
  └─┬ ts-loader@8.3.0
    └── loader-utils@2.0.2 deduped

The resolutions are all in a parent package.json file.
